# Obtaining Current Time

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am trying to understand how can I obtain the current time of the audio while the audio is playing. So when the audio starts playing it will log 0 and at the end of play it will log the total duration. This is what I have tried below and it is not returning what I had in mind. I am probably doing it wrong. But I am not sure where it is going wrong.

For example, at the end of the audio, it returns `currentTime:36.02133333333333 totalDuration36.006875` where currentTime>totalDuration which is completely wrong. I want to utilize these values, hence they need to be accurate.

```js
const audioUrl = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/128337/ongoing-thing-crop.ogg';  

/*test url2 - https://s.cdpn.io/1202/Star_Wars_original_opening_crawl_1977.mp3*/

const div = document.querySelector('div');

const audioContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
let bufferSource = audioContext.createBufferSource();
let analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
let gainNode = audioContext.createGain();

let startTime;

async function setupAudio(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const audioData = await response.arrayBuffer();
    const buffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(audioData);

    bufferSource.buffer = buffer;
    bufferSource.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

    function updateTime() {
        let currentTime = audioContext.currentTime - startTime;
        console.log(`currentTime:${currentTime}`,`totalDuration${buffer.duration}`);
        if (currentTime < buffer.duration) {
            requestAnimationFrame(updateTime);
        }
    }

    div.addEventListener('change', () => {
        startTime = audioContext.currentTime;
        bufferSource.start(0);
        requestAnimationFrame(updateTime);
    });
}

setupAudio(audioUrl);
```

```html
<div id="selector">
  <label for="valueSelection">Choose a value <select id="valueSelection">
      <option>off</option>
      <option>on</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
<audio></audio>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happens because the code is printing console output outside of the conditional check in `updateTime` function:

```
   function updateTime() {
        let currentTime = audioContext.currentTime - startTime;
        console.log(`currentTime:${currentTime}`,`totalDuration${buffer.duration}`);
        if (currentTime < buffer.duration) {
            requestAnimationFrame(updateTime);
        }
    }
```

What you are basically doing is printing console log output in following cases:

- Print log every time when `currentTime` is less than `buffer.duration` , and
- Print log once when `currentTime` is greater than or equal to `buffer.duration`

**Note:** During last log output when currentTime > totalDuration, you actually aren't calling the function `updateTime`, since the conditional checking will be `false`:

```
      // false when currentTime >= buffer.duration
      // so you won't call updateTime, but you are printing console log once
       if (currentTime < buffer.duration) {
            requestAnimationFrame(updateTime);
        }
```

##### To fix the issue, just move the console log statement inside your conditional checking logic like following:

```
   function updateTime() {
        let currentTime = audioContext.currentTime - startTime;
                if (currentTime < buffer.duration) {
                console.log(`currentTime:${currentTime}`,`totalDuration${buffer.duration}`);
                requestAnimationFrame(updateTime);
        }
    }
```

This will only print console log output when `currentTime < buffer.duration` is `true`.

#### Check following modified code:

```js
const audioUrl = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/128337/ongoing-thing-crop.ogg';

/*test url2 - https://s.cdpn.io/1202/Star_Wars_original_opening_crawl_1977.mp3*/

const div = document.querySelector('div');

const audioContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
let bufferSource = audioContext.createBufferSource();
let analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
let gainNode = audioContext.createGain();

let startTime;

async function setupAudio(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const audioData = await response.arrayBuffer();
  const buffer = await audioContext.decodeAudioData(audioData);

  bufferSource.buffer = buffer;
  bufferSource.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

  function updateTime() {
    let currentTime = audioContext.currentTime - startTime;
    if (currentTime < buffer.duration) {
      console.log(`currentTime:${currentTime}`, `totalDuration${buffer.duration}`);
      requestAnimationFrame(updateTime);
    }
  }

  div.addEventListener('change', () => {
    startTime = audioContext.currentTime;
    bufferSource.start(0);
    requestAnimationFrame(updateTime);
  });
}

setupAudio(audioUrl);
```

```html
<div id="selector">
  <label for="valueSelection">Choose a value <select id="valueSelection">
      <option>off</option>
      <option>on</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</div>
<audio></audio>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I have two follow-up question to this. When I run this on firefox, it never logs 0 at the start of audio, in chrome and edge it logs 0 at the start. In all 3 browsers, at the end of audio, it does not log the exact duration. I was hoping that if an audio finishes at `36.006875`; the last currentTime should be `36.006875`. Also, I am doing it through `rAf` to continuously log the current time. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: The first question's answer is it's happening due to Chrome and Edge both using the same V8 engine and Firefox using a different engine. And the last currentTime can not be printed when the audio finishes, as it totally depends on requesetAnimationFrame's callback function, which is usually 60 times per second by default or equal to browser refresh rate as per W3C recommendation. And according to my knowledge, rAF is the best way of doing it.